# How can I get DataGridView row values and store them in variables?

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can I loop through the rows of a `DataGridView` one at a time (I have 2 columns), then store those 2 columns in a variable that will be used as a parameter for an sql query?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow Datarow in contentTable_grd.Rows)
{
    contentValue1 = Datarow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    contentValue2 = Datarow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    
    SqlParameter param4 = new SqlParameter("@contentTableValue1", contentValue1);
    SqlParameter param5 = new SqlParameter("@contentTableValue2", contentValue2);
}
```

I'm getting this error when using the above code:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: What are you wanting to do that your code doesn't achieve?

Comment: @andrewcooper I have 2 columns and for each row i want to get those values and store it in a variable which will then be inserted into a database then move onto the next row.

Comment: Which line is giving the error?  Does `contentTable_grd` exist?

Comment: From what I can see you're doing what you're wanting to do.  All you need is the SQL statement to insert the values in the database.

Comment: @andrewCooper I need to get the values from the gridview first how can i do that? btw the gridview isnt bound to a datasource and im populating it through either user input or importing a file which uses regex to find certain things and insert into the datagridview

Comment: @andrewcooper the line that is giving the error is the contentvalue1 = Datarow.cells......
and the next line will give the error as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem I needed an if statement to prevent empty cells from going through

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow Datarow in contentTable_grd.Rows)
    {
        if (Datarow.Cells[0].Value != null && Datarow.Cells[1].Value != null)
        {
            contentValue1 = Datarow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            contentValue2 = Datarow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(contentValue1);
            MessageBox.Show(contentValue2);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Good catch.  One thing you might consider, which is sometimes you WANT to pass null values to your procedure...  Also -- checkout string.isnullorempty() as a possible replacement for != NULL...

Answer (score 5):

The most likely problem is that the one or both the Cell's you're referencing contains a null value and the exception is thrown when you attempt to call `ToString()` on such a cell.

One solution is to use the [?? operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) to return a default value for your parameter if a Cell Value is null:

```
contentValue1 = Datarow.Cells[0].Value ?? string.Empty;
contentValue2 = Datarow.Cells[1].Value ?? string.Empty;
```

This code will return an empty string if a cell's Value is null; you might wish to use a different default.

Answer (score 1):

what is contentValue1?

Not sure about c# -- can it implicitly type the variable?  Maybe try something like `string contentvalue1 = ...`

Also, depending on what kind of control might be in the cell...you might do something like

`string contentvalue1 = CTYPE(DataRow.FindControl("myTextbox"),textbox).text`